# Who are the five Lords of Hell in the Black Soulstone?

Tags: diablo-iii

After you obtain the Black Soulstone is Act II you can talk to Adria and it is several times mentioned that there is already five Lords of Hell in the Soulstone. Who are these five?

To my knowledge there are six Lords of Hell, I think we can be fairly certain that Diablo, Mephisto, Baal and Andariel are all in the Soulstone, that leaves two of of the six Lords of Hell. Belial and Azmodan, seeing as they by that point still haven't been fought surely they can't be in the Soulstone. Is this an error by Blizzard or is there some Lord of Hell that hasn't had a good pr guy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting everyone's (least) favorite Prince of Pain, Duriel, remembered mainly for being one of the most bastardly bosses in Diablo II.

Comment: That Holy Freeze aura + knockback was a pain :)

Comment: More like that long loading screen delay + charge. ;)

Comment: Imagine fighting Duriel without Town Portal... such fun!

Answer (score 6):

[There are seven Great Evils](http://www.diablowiki.net/Great_Evils); you're forgetting Duriel. So, I'm guessing Andariel, Duriel, Mephisto, Diablo, and Baal.

Comment: Ah right of course, Duriel. Guess I forgot him since he seems like such a minor character in the story of Diablo 2. Honestly also seems that he is rarely mention as a Lesser Evil, granted it's been a while since I played D2.